# Is it possible to move from windows to linux Azure App Service easily?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

As I see I need to create new linux app service.
Recreate domain, certificates binding and deployment pipeline.
And then remove old one.
Is it simplier way to do this?

Comment: Is that you have a windows app service and you want to move it to linux app service?

Comment: Yes and do this right

Comment: As far as I knew, it does not have an easy way to do that. Because they have different OS version. For more details, please refer to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/31599205-option-to-migrate-windows-webapp-to-linux-webapp. So I think you need to create a new app , deploy your code to the app and configure other things for the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Jim Xu mentioned it is currently not possible to move the WebApp from Windows based to Linux. You may have to redeploy the App, leverage the same code with slight modifications and configuration changes as per the requirement. 
Cloning feature is not available at the time of [this writing](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#current-restrictions). Also, currently there is a [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations) - You cannot create a Linux Web App in an App Service plan already hosting non-Linux Web Apps.

Copying the [Uservoice post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/31599205-option-to-migrate-windows-webapp-to-linux-webapp) here for clarity & convenience:

" Unfortunately we can’t provide this feature as there are too many internal dependencies for the underlying OS that would make this complex and potentially breaking for solutions. There definitely could be languages that might be supported but they would an edge case."

We really appreciate your feedback/suggestion, so kindly up-vote the Uservoice post -All of the feedback you share there will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Comment: Equally vexing is the second limitation "Based on a current limitation, for the same resource group you cannot mix Windows and Linux apps in the same region."