# Azure: change an existing Windows Web App to a Linux Web App (docker)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have an existing Windows Web App in Azure which I want to migrate to a Linux (docker) Web App. It is easy to setup a new Linux Web App with a new URI and that all works. However, I need to preserve the existing URI (myservice.azurewebsites.net) that I have on the Windows Web App and use it in the Linux Web App.

Any downtime is not acceptable, so I cannot just "test" if I can remove the current Windows Web App and "re-use" the same URI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to move from windows to linux Azure App Service easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404734/is-it-possible-to-move-from-windows-to-linux-azure-app-service-easily)

Comment: Unfortunately not. My problem is that I need to preserve the existing URI. You always get a new URI if you create a new web app and I don't know how to change that one.

Comment: You can't preserve that URL

Comment: And do you have any idea how long it will take until the existing URI is "freed" after deleting the existing Windows Web App.

Answer (score 0):

Created `ASP.Net Core Web App` and deployed to Azure Windows App Service.

Tried to deploy the same Web App to Linux App Service(Docker), got the below warning.
[image]

- Tried to continue the steps to provide the configuration access to docker container, got the below error.
  [image]
- For the apps which we want to deploy in `Azure Linux Docker`, we need to `Enable Docker` and provide `Docker OS` , which is not required for Azure Windows App Service.
  [image]

> remove the current Windows Web App and "re-use" the same URI.

- It is suggested to create a new App Service Plan and deploy to Linux App (Docker).